# Find address using latitude/ longitude attribute (Python & geopy)

Tags: python, geopy

I have been trying to resolve a particular problem - extract location/address out of the predefined list. The list represents e-mail message where address will **definitely** be. I have not found any efficient way how to do it, however, I was able to come with some idea.

I might go through the message using for loop and state, whether the sequence of words has attribute of longitude/latitude. If not, the word will be deleted, if yes, the word will remain in the new list and loop will go through next words.

This way I can distinguish which words are address and I can surely extract the address. Do you think this way might be efficient? If not, is there any more complex/better way how to extract the address out of a string?

For example:

`email = "Hello, I am looking forward to your letter, please send it on 20 W 34th St, New York, NY 10001, USA"`

I want to extract:

`adress = "20 W 34th St, New York, NY 10001, USA"`

I have this piece of code:

```
email = email.split()
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
adress_scan = []
geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent = "sth", timeout = 10)

for i in adresa:
    adresa_scan.append(i)
    location = geolocator.geocode(str(adresa_scan))
    if hasattr(adresa_scan, 'longitude') == False:
        adresa_scan.remove(i)   
print(adresa_scan)
```

The program keeps printing empty list and I don't know why. Thank you, I appreciate any help:)

Comment: Can you please define adresa?

Comment: @dtc348 oh, that is a small error - adresa should be adress, that must have happened during variable names translation, thanks for reminding:)

Comment: Hey, just use this code. import pyap; addresses = pyap.parse(email, country='US'); print(addresses)

Comment: @dtc348 thanks, yes that works of course, but it supports only US, GB and Canadian adresses. Is there any way how to parse adresses all around the world (e.g. European)?

Comment: I think we do not have any python Library for addresses for all around the world. That's why I am using Google API, Where you need to give parameters like, website, name of the company.

Comment: @dtc348 That's the thing, there is no available library for this problem - that's why I thought about using geopy and latitude/longitude. Would you please help me with this idea, assuming it is appropriate?